# Экспорт JET-графика в MS Word

Tags: ms-word, oracle-apex

Есть web-страница, сформированная Oracle APEX 5, содержащая среди прочего график (JET chart). Как скопировать страницу в Word? Обычный copy график игнорирует. Понятно, что график не является картинкой, а является js-объектом. Что делать?

Comment: ничего сложного нет, если Вы знакомы с .NET. в этом случае Вам надо: 1) выбрать библиотеку для работы с MSWord, например Aspose, 2) написать свою библиотеку, которая используя первую будет писать в MSWord то, что Вам нужно, 3) интегрироваться с Oracle Apex. Если честно, выглядит устрашающе. Возможно лучше подойти со стороны Oracle APEX->pdf(или html)->docx

Comment: опять же, раз является js-объектом, то значит он рисуется в виде svg, либо html5. Определите, в каком формате он рисуется. Вам нужен конвертер из этого формата. Лучше всего конвертер реализовать на сервере (пользователь жмякает кнопку, svg перегоняется на сервер, возвращается png)

Comment: APEX может работать с Jasper reports, думаю, вам надо в ту сторону копать.